# Decryption providing a padding error

Tags: c#, encryption, rijndael

I'm trying to save a serialized object to an encrypted file. This isn't production quality and I am aware of the security risks with the way that I am doing this, but ignoring those I will have a key in a resource (data.Settings.key) that wont change and I have a salt that is also a constant.

My encryption seems to work, but decryption returns me an Exception saying that padding is invalid and cannot be closed when I try to close my CryptoStream.

```
    private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] bytes)
    {
        var decryptor = algorithm.CreateDecryptor();
        using (var sMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var sCryptoStream = new CryptoStream(sMemoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            sCryptoStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            sCryptoStream.Close();
            return sMemoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

The algorithm variable is the same one that the encrypt method uses and is built by this method which is called in the classes constructor:

```
    private static SymmetricAlgorithm GetAlgorithm()
    {
        var algorithm = Rijndael.Create();

        // Create key from salt and password in config
        var rdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(data.Settings.key, new byte[] {
            0x44,0x61,0x79,0x6e,0x65,0x44,0x6f,0x75,0x67,0x61,0x6e
        });
        algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        // Set key and IV from rdb
        algorithm.Key = rdb.GetBytes(32);
        algorithm.IV = rdb.GetBytes(16);
        return algorithm;
    }
```

I've tried changing the padding mode in the algorithm but I can't understand why it's fine with this padding when encrypting, but now when decrypting.

If it helps here is the method that calls the decrypt method:

```
    private static User OpenFile(String sUserName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Opening file...");
        using (Stream sFileStream = new FileStream(data.Settings.dir + "data\\accounts\\" + sUserName + ".dat",
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
        using (Stream sMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Read from File to memory stream
            sFileStream.CopyTo(sMemoryStream);

            // Decrypt data and store in new memory stream
            byte[] bytes = new byte[sMemoryStream.Length];
            Console.WriteLine("\tb:" + bytes.Length);
            bytes = decrypt(bytes);
            Console.WriteLine("\ta:" + bytes.Length);
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            Console.WriteLine("\ts:" + bytes.Length);

            // Deserialise memory stream and return as User object
            User user = (User)bfFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
            return user;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no need for most of that code.  The binaryformatter simply needs a stream, so you can pass it a cryptostream (wrapping a filestream) rather than jump thru all those hoops.  Hard to tell whats wrong with the decryption without seeing the encryption